# How to create temp folder to store a file from external directory and use it in a game

Tags: unity, c#, 3d-modeling

I would like to copy a 3D model from external library and save it in temp/Resources/StreamingAssets folder to instantiate an object in unity scene. 
`

```
public class FBXOBJLoader : MonoBehaviour {

    string src;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        src = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Select Model", "", "fbx");
        //Output the Game data path to the console
        Debug.Log("Path : " + src);
        StartCoroutine("CopySomething");
    }

    IEnumerator CopySomething()
    {
        print("Start");
        string path;
        path = Application.temporaryCachePath;
        FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory(src,path);     
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

It's creating some unknown file format in the asset folder. can anybody please help me to complete this task.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Now it's storing in temp. does anybody know how to use it in unity scene?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `Application.temporaryCachePath` returns the folder, you need the intended filepath. If you print it to the console it looks like this: `C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Temp/SomeCompanyName/SomeProjectName`

Therefore, to fix the issue, change:

```
path = Application.temporaryCachePath;
```

To:

```
path = string.Concat(Application.temporaryCachePath, "/", Path.GetFileName(src));
```

Note, to use `Path.GetFileName` you must add `using System.IO` to the top of your script.

Comment: after that how can i instantiate an object into unity scene. consider my 3D model name is "flask". Now i selected the flask it not showing any error now can you please tell me how to use it

Comment: That is a whole other question in itself. I suggest you accept the answer for this specific question if it solved your issue and ask a separate question about instantiating an FBX at runtime.

Comment: it is a part of my question. Please check my title and content. i clearly asked 
 - in title -> how to use it in game?
 - in message body -> temp/Resources/StreamingAssets folder to instantiate an object in unity scene.

Comment: If you insist, then I suggest you have a search on google first. There is plenty of help available.

Comment: Sorry mr-matt, I am requesting you. you are the person helping me here. i just want to show the 3d model from external folder to unity scene. for that i tried many ways but failed. now i am trying a new method to copy the selected 3d model to my application temp and try to use this. so only i raised this question. if my words hurt you i am really very very sorry for that. Hope i ll get help and Thanks

Comment: No no you didn't offend me, I just think it would be more helpful to the rest of the gamedev community if you ask a question about loading an FBX at runtime separately.

Comment: Thanks for that. i raised a new question please click the url to find the new question.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/165457/73422